# Why the method 'replace' does not work properly, using keySet for a Map?

Tags: java, keyset

There is a map (tickets), where the key is the players' tips (as a set) and the value, which is 0 before checking the ticket and should update after checking the tips with the hits.
I make an intersection on the tips and the winning numbers for each ticket lines. The new size of the set gives the hit result and should replace in the map.
As the result shows below, the key updates well, but the value not. What is the problem?

```
public void ticketCheck() {
        
    // tickets and winningNumbers will come as parameters, now it is only an example:
    Map<Set<Integer>,Integer> tickets = new HashMap<Set<Integer>,Integer>(){
        {
            put(new HashSet<Integer>(Set.of(5,21,25,32,38,40)) ,0); 
            put(new HashSet<Integer>(Set.of(8,11,17,29,32,45)) ,0); 
        };
    };
        
    Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(Set.of(11,20,32,33,36,45));
        
    Iterator<Set<Integer>> itr = tickets.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {         
            Set<Integer> oneTicket = itr.next();
            oneTicket.retainAll(winningNumbers); // intersection of the tips and winning numbers
            int result = oneTicket.size();  
            tickets.replace(oneTicket,result);
    }
                
    for (Map.Entry<Set<Integer>, Integer> item : tickets.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(item.getKey() + " hits: "+item.getValue());
    }               
}
```

The result:

```
[32] hits: 0
[32, 11, 45] hits: 0
```

but should be:

```
[32] hits: 1
[32, 11, 45] hits: 3
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use mutable objects as keys (unless of course you don't mutate them).

Comment: Try it like this. `tickets = tickets.keySet().stream().map(set->{
set.retainAll(winningNumbers);return set;}).collect(Collectors.toMap(set->set, set->set.size()));`

Comment: [Don’t use double brace initialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)  (And I’m surprised you would use it, since if you know about the Set.of methods, you probably know about the Map.of methods.)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. The stream solution works perfectly!